# WAMP icon colors

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I'm running Wamp 3.0.0 64bit on Windows 10. In past versions the icon was either red, orange or green depending on status. Now the green version has a red dot in it, and the background color is pale yellow rather than clear as it is on the red and orange versions.

Does anyone know the significance of the background color or the red dot?

Comment: That sounds a little odd, it should not do that unless your screen is doing something odd. Oh and there is a `WAMPServer 3.0.4` which fixes a few little things. You can apply `WAMPServer3.0.4` straight over the top of `WAMPServer 3.0.0` [See the forum for details](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the new version, I'll probably upgrade tonight.

Comment: I haven't been able to connect to the download page to get the update, tried yesterday evening and today.

Comment: Try the backup download site [here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) Or go direct to [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I gave you some wrong advice above in my comments.

The icon you speak about is in fact a new Icon I had forgotten about.

This image [image] indicates that you have set WAMPServer Online i.e. you have used the `Online/Offline` menu and set Apache to be `Online`.

**NOTE:** It is not necessary to have set Apache Online for normal development activity. `Online` only means that Apache can be accessed by any IP Address in the universe.

In other words when Online the `httpd.conf` file contains this parameter in the

```
<Directory "D:/wamp/www/">
```

section on `httpd.conf`

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted
```

when normally it has

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

Unless you are actually trying to access your site from the internet it is not required to be Online.

**Additional info after clarification**

Ok, so if you are just trying to open up to connections from your local network then you have to do this. WAMPServer3 added the use of localhost as a Virtual Host by default. So now you should leave the `httpd.conf` files as

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

Now edit `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\conf\extra\httpd-vhost.conf` and add your access requirements to that like this

The default is this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So just add requirements like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local

        Require ip 192.168.0.1
        Require ip 192.168.0.2
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or add this for any ip in your local network

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local

        Require ip 192.168.0
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, this makes much more sense.  I'm trying for a setting that will let me get to the server through my local WiFi from phone & tablet, but NOT for outside my local network. I thought that was what the online switch was for.  BTW, I did download the newest version of WAMP64, but unlike your suggestion, it would NOT install over version 3.0.0. Too worried about destroying a 2x version, I guess. Safety first isn't something I can get mad at.

Comment: Ah, I think V3.0.3 will and then you apply the addon V3,0,4